# What does this ping error mean?

Tags: windows-vista, networking

What does the following ping error mean and how do I fix it?

```
Pinging 0.0.0.0 with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed, error code 1214.
PING: transmit failed, error code 1214.
PING: transmit failed, error code 1214.
PING: transmit failed, error code 1214.

Ping statistics for 0.0.0.0:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

I believe this required to connect to my broadband internet.

Comment: What did you do to get this error message from ping?

Comment: Try pinging a valid address such as 212.58.251.197 and see what you get.

Answer (score 7):

I think it's pretty self explanatory "transmit failed" means the packets could not be sent to that address. To fix it simply don't ping that address.

`0.0.0.0` is typically used when writing socket code as a server host address. This is so that the server is reachable from all interfaces on the machine. It is the default network address and routers these days will deal with it accordingly and it usually wont go any further, since ISPs will drop those packets (as it would wreak havoc being sent to everyone, which it used to do). It used to be for broadcasting a packet to every available subnet but was replaced by `255.255.255.255`.

Comment: You can also use (*sysinternals*) `psping64 -t -4 <ip>` to get a more informative message. Sometimes the network is blocked by local firewall, and you'd get a `Access is denied.` message.

Answer (score 5):

To look up error messages you can use `net helpmsg`:

```
> net helpmsg 1214

The format of the specified network name is invalid.
```

Other than that what John T wrote might be correct and therefore the longer answer (I tend to forget everything about networks as soon as I learn it; I'm simply happy when they work; same with hardware :-)).

Answer (score 0):

In layman's terms, it usually is an indicator that you have lost your connection between your PC and router/modem.

**WHY**

- Typically this is due to loss of power at the router/modem/switch. It could also mean that you cannot receive a dynamic IP address because the DHCP server (whether it's a router or server) cannot be reached.

**WHAT TO CHECK**

- I would make sure that your ETHERNET cable in plugged in and that you see a light on the back of your system where you plug the cable in. If you're using WIRELESS, then make sure that you have a strong signal and little to no interference (those darn cordless phones and microwaves)!
- Next if you are using your own router between your ISP's modem and your computer, then make sure that you can login to your router and use the built-in PING utility to ensure that you can ping.

  - If you can, then you may have a mis-configuration on your router, or a bad ethernet cable.
  - If you can't, then you may want to plug directly into the ISP provided modem and see if you can receive a dynamic IP address and ping from there.